# Single-valued enumeration of all c.e. sets

Tags: computability, enumeration

Please help prove the following statement:

> There exists a single-valued computable enumeration of the family of computably enumerable sets.

Definitions:

1) Let $S$ be nonempty countable set (possibly finite). Any surjective map $\nu\colon \omega \twoheadrightarrow S$ from the set $\omega$ of natural numbers onto the set $S$ is called an enumeration.

2) An enumeration  $\nu$ is single-valued if $\nu$ is a bijective, i.e.  $\nu(x) \neq   \nu(y)$ for any $x \ne y$.

Comment: I assume that you represent a c.e. set by a Turing machine $M$, and by "single-valued" you mean that $L(\nu(x)) \neq L(\nu(y))$, where $L(M)$ is the set of inputs on which $M$ halts.

Comment: By the way, in the problem statement I corrected "a family of c.e. sets" to "the family of c.e. sets". Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then it is a classic result of Friedberg, [Three Theorems on Recursive Enumeration](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964290).

Comment: I don't represent a c.e. set by a Turing machine

Comment: You'll have to explain how you do represent it.

Comment: I represent a c.e. set  as A ⊆ ω.  Family of  c.e. sets is set of A.

Comment: You can convert a representation by Turing machines to your kind of representation by simply running the machine.